# React-router-dom переход на новую стравнуци, на на нужную секцию

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

В реакте с react-router-dom я перехожу с одной страницы, на другую, но кроме перехода, мне нужно прокрутить страницу, до нужной секций. вроде не сложно, через id на секцию... но не могу понять как в NavLink указать это.
пример
Сюда необходимо прейти.

```
return (
<section className="newsCategories__section" id="newsCategories">
  <div className="container">
    <h2 className="newsCategories__title">Categories</h2>
    <ul className="newsCategories__list">
      <li....
```

вот NavLink-

```
<div className="newsCard__wrapper--categoryAndDate">
        <NavLink
          className="newsCard__category"
          to={/News#newsCategories}
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch(setCategories(category));
          }}
        >
          {category}
        </NavLink>
        <time className="newsCard__date" dateTime="">
          {date}
        </time>
      </div>
```

Нашел, где то, что можно через # но надежды не оправдались

Comment: Так в текущем коде и так не правильно указано "to".

Comment: Это указана попытка, сделать переход на нужный элемент, нашел в одном из форумов, но оно не оправдало надежды как я и написал.
и при таком коде, переход работает, но не переходит на нужную секцию.

Comment: Я думаю метод с якорем не сработает. Думаю в компоненте где вы рендерите страницу, для которой вам нужно сделать скролл к элементу. Вам нужно это сделать через `useEffect` и `element.scrollBy`.

Comment: хмммм... но на разных экранах, придется делать скролл на разную высоту.... все же думаю, должен быть выход.

Comment: Зачем? Мы скролим к элементу.

Comment: Действительно... вы правы. Я не подумал над такой возможностью.
Спасибо

Comment: Еще можно попробовать через ref. Не делал, не проверял, может через часика 3. Что если попробовать создать тег a, там указать href='#someid' и в useeffect сделать ref.click(). Вдруг сработает )

Comment: @SwaD, а смысл в этом? Мы же можем и без `ref` по сути методами `js`, что конечно не приветствуется найти элемент с нужным `id`. Но уж проще дать `ref` и в `useEffect` сделать для него `scrollBy`, я дума. самый правильный способ.